Sonar Quality gate status not showing i Bitbucket Pull Request
we are using sonarqube 9.9 LTS enterprise edition and with that we are exploring Devops platform integration feature in sonarqube so that to have the Sonar quality gate status on the Bitbucket Pull request. I went through the sonar docs and based on that I have created the Configuration for Bitbucket Cloud and now after the Jenkins Pipeline successful build and successfull sonar scan when I create a PR for my branch I don’t see Quality Gate status on the Pull request.
Steps Done to create the Bitbucket Configuration on sonarqube:
Go to global DevOps Platform integration settings and create the configuration for Bitbucket.
Create Oauth consumer to report Quality gate status on PR with PR:Read Permissions.
Update the below settings and save the configuration:
• Configuration Name
• Workspace ID
• OAuth Key
• Oauth Secret
Configure project settings by adding configuration name and repository slug to report Quality Gate status in manually created or existing projects.
Bitbucket configuration on sonarqube:
enter image description here
Bitbucket Pullrequest not showing Quality Gate status:
enter image description here
Below is what I could see in sonar logs after the project analysis is done on my branch:
enter image description here
Could you please tell is there anything which I am missing as part of using this feature?
Please help with it as i am new to this feature in sonar.
